# Find the limit and see if this expression is right

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to calculate the following limit:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left (\sqrt[3]{(n+2)^2}-\sqrt[3]{(n-2)^2} \right)$$

**Attempt:** I tried to get rid of the third roots by multiplying and dividing by $\sqrt[3]{(n+2)^4}+\sqrt[3]{(n+2)^2(n-2)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(n-2)^4}$, and then I simplified the numerator. I could get to

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{8n^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{\left (\frac{n+2}{n} \right)^4}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{n^2-4}{n^4}}+\sqrt[3]{\left (\frac{n-2}{n} \right)^4}}$$

See the image below for more details on my attempt.

I am not sure if my attempt is correct and I am not sure how to proceed.

**Remark**: The text above clearly describes the question and the attempt. The image is no longer an essential part of question. It is kept only as a reference and, if it is necessary, it can be deleted.

[image]

Comment: Hi Lizz, please edit your question to provide information that is more relevant to the question

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Posting a question trapped in an image is problematic. Handwriting can be hard to read, but even the most legible text is inaccessible to visually-impaired users who require screen readers; moreover, the content of an image-only question isn't searchable. Please consult [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/409) for formatting your expressions using MathJax. (You have a bit of a daunting first exercise for attempting this, but do what you can and others can help.)

Comment: You forgot one square in the midle term fo the denominator. The final expression should be: 

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{8n^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{\left (\frac{n+2}{n} \right)^4}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{(n^2-4)^2}{n^4}}+\sqrt[3]{\left (\frac{n-2}{n} \right)^4}}$$

Can you proceed from here? **Hint:** Can you apply the limit to numerator and denominator separately?

Comment: Rewrite the expression as $n^\frac{2}{3} ( (1+2/n)^\frac{2}{3}-(1-2/n)^\frac{2}{3})$ and do a Taylor expansion.

Comment: For what it is worth, the your image was very helpful in following your work.  Perhaps you have already figured this out,  if not, following up on @Ramiro's comment from yesterday, recall that:  $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n^{-\frac{1}{3}}=0$, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n+2}{n}=1$, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n^2-4)^2}{n^4}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n^2-4)}{n^2}\cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(n^2-4)}{n^2}=1\cdot1 = 1$, and $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n-2}{n}=1$.  Can you proceed from here?